# How to apply clustering algorithms to a volume surface?

Tags: python, vtk, paraview, openfoam

I’m trying to compare some OpenFOAM CFD simulations that reproduce the flow through an almost spherical object(the object is a reconstruction, with an irregular shape), searching for the one with the smallest cluster of wall shear stress. So, I want to know if there is a way of running a clustering algorithm on this irregular surface, like K Means, EM or other unsupervised algorithm. In other words, I would like to numerically compare the colormap plotted in slightly different shapes, taking the area and the mean value of the clusters as parameters to do this comparison, for example. Someone has ever handled a similar situation?

I've already tried to project this object to a plane or a sphere, but the distortion was greater than expected, and this became no longer an option.